# Тяф-тяф, но тяВкать. Почему?

Tags: орфография, лексика, однокоренные-слова

> Перекрой мне кислород и запрети мне доступ, я всего лишь подросток, но люблю просто.
>   Размажь меня по полу, испепели без остатка, чтобы не смел больше **тяфкать** и понял вкус несладкий ( [Nebo7](http://tekstovoi.ru/text/95159359_950083105p918977017_text_pesni_perekroj_mne_kislorod_i_zapreti_mne.html)).
>
> ...она хотела было поиграть с ними, но они испугались ее и убежали, а вместо них появился какой-то черный зверек и так страшно принялся на нее **тяфкать**, что русалка перепугалась и уплыла назад в море... ([Х. К. Андерсен. Русалочка](http://www.sky-art.com/andersen/tales/ru/016_1_ru.htm))

Знаю:  *тя**в**кать, тя**в**канье, тя**в**кающий*...
Но: **ТЯФ**
Звукоподражательное слово, также междометие; неизменяемое.
Корень: -тяф-.

Хотелось бы понять:
1) выделенные глаголы использованы ошибочно?
2) есть какие-либо *исключения* или *особенности* (возможно, авторские) в их применении?
3) кроме **тяф-тяф**, **Тяфка** (кличка), что еще существует с этим корнем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В теме, связанной со звукоподражательными словами, не очень много  логики, поэтому здесь можно только ознакомиться с определенными фактами:

**1) Написание этих слов нормировано в современных словарях как тявкать, гавкать, тяв-тяв, гав-гав**

Форма "тяфкать" встречается только в словаре Ушакова (работа по созданию "Толкового словаря русского языка" велась с 1934 по 1940 год):  **ТЯВКАТЬ,** тяфкаю, тяфкаешь, несов. 1. Отрывисто лаять (преимущ. о маленьких собаках) (разг.). Сонно тяфкали собаки. Максим Горький. 2. перен. Ворчать, браниться (простореч. вульг.).

2) **Такая норма написания внутренне противоречива**

С одной стороны, мы стараемся точно воспроизвести звуки собачьего лая, с другой ― пишем тяв, тявкать, а произносим тяф, тяфкать, оглушая согласный В по орфоэпической норме.

3) **Надо сказать, что пользователи русского языка во все времена достаточно свободно записывали "собачий лай"**

Раньше (до 1956 года) не было строгих правил, а сейчас в сетевых записках к помощи правил не всегда обращаются, например: (1) Сыщики ответили коротко: ― Тяф! И помчались на пустырь особым хитрым галопом, занося задние ноги вбок. [А. Н. Толстой. Золотой ключик, или приключения Буратино (1936)] (2) "Право не знаю в какую тему написать, моя пёса каждый день тяфкает, слегка гафкает во сне.  Это нормально?"

**4. А правильно ли мы слышим звуки, которые издают животные?**

В «Песенке старого Макдональда» мы встречаем домашних животных, издающих характерные звуки. Это утка, корова, собака и поросенок.
В процессе исследования мы выяснили, что **некоторые домашние животные издают в английском и русском языке звуки одинаково**. В частности, корова и в русском, и в английском языке мычит, когда их пора доить moo(англ.) и му- му (рус.): А вот большинство животных выражает свои эмоции в этих языках по-разному. **Наша собака лает гав-гав, когда она злится, когда она дружелюбна -тяв- тяв, а вот английская bow-wow или woof-woof.**

[Звукоподражание в английском и русском языках на примерах поэтических произведений | bibliofond.ru](http://bibliofond.ru/view.aspx?id=667139)

**5. Вывод**

**Точного соответствия** между звуками, издаваемыми животными, и фонетикой конкретного языка **быть не может**, поэтому их запись имеет чисто условный характер. **Это просто волевое решение, которое принято уже очень давно и  которое требует неукоснительного исполнения.** Поэтому все грамотные люди должны писать **"тявкать и тяв-тяв"**, а всё остальные рассуждения ― это только история вопроса, но не сам вопрос.

Comment: Простите, а где в словаре Ушакова вы нашли "тя**ф**кать"? http://ushakovdictionary.ru/word.php?wordid=78790

Comment: Думаю, что словарь Ушакова имел несколько редкций http://netiquette.narod.ru/d/f9/p90834.html

Comment: У меня есть два разных издания: одно — первой половины 20 в., второе — ужасная современная переделка (где такие же статьи. как и на вашем сайте). Везде только *тя**в**кать*. Я бы не доверял вашему источнику.

Comment: Под редакцией и при авторском участии Д. Н. Ушакова (1873 - 1942), в 1935—1940 годах, вышло 4 тома «Толкового словаря русского языка»,  2-е издание словаря вышло в 1947—1948 годах.  Нужно в этих изданиях смотреть.

Comment: я и смотрел в этом издании (2-м).

Comment: Остается под вопросом первое издание. Вообще говоря, в Нацкорпусе "тяфкать" нет, а вот "тяф" встречается (41 пример).

Comment: О господи, Sibylla, вы действительно верите, что такой опытный коллектив филологов, который работал над словарем Ушакова, на самом деле смог бы допустить такую дурацкую небрежность?.. Как в заглавии словарной статьи и в его формах могут быть разные написания?

Comment: А Вы уверены, что над первым изданием словаря работал опытный коллектив филологов? Есть информация, что всё это происходило  в далеко не идеальных условиях, драматическая такая история. И ошибок, неточностей в первом издании много, что-то правилось, возможно, на ходу. На самом деле, наверное, было исправлено первое слово этой статьи, если судить по дальнейшему тексту. И сейчас в Сети многие дают ссылку на Ушакова, когда обсуждается "тявкать или тяфкать",

Comment: в общем, мне нечего добавить к своим словам. Позвольте, рассказывать про историю создания словаря не буду (но она довольно сложная). В интернете много чего обсуждают...

Answer (score 1):

*Тя**в***, в отличие от *тя**ф***, фиксируется словарями (см. "Новый словарь русского языка" Т. Ф. Ефремовой, http://orfo.ruslang.ru/search/word). Верным также будут написания *тя**в**-тя**в***, *тя**в**кать*.

С точки зрения орфографии написания с буквой *ф* ненормативны.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант "тяфкать" является случайно кем-то ошибочно зафиксированным вариантом от "тявкать", который был некоторыми воспринят и продолжен. На самом деле внутри этого слова имела место обыкновенная регрессивная ассимиляция согласных, когда предыдущий звук (здесь звонкий "В"), настраиваясь на произнесение последующего звука (здесь глухой "К"), уподоблялся ему и в результате оглушился и превратился в "Ф", то есть в некоторую производную, называемую в лингвистике фонемой. Поэтому "тявкать" слышится как "тяфкать". Кто-то записал, как слышал и пошло, поехало.

Comment: А как насчет варианта "тяф"― Тяф да тяф, только и знают, что лают дворняжки! [М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Пошехонская старина).  (1887-1889)]  Пузатенькая собачонка, видимо, в подражание хозяину, тоже в такт с ним, покряхтывала: «Тяф! [В. Я. Шишков. Угрюм-река. Ч. 5-8 (1913-1932)]  Это "тяф" как записывали - по слуху или с учетом оглушения?

Comment: И как-то странно вы определяете фонему. Неужели  Ф здесь "некоторая производная, называемая в лингвистике фонемой"? Это по какой фонологической школе?